# Cannot get Step Debugging to work in Eclipse/CF 8

Tags: coldfusion

I just can't seem to get step debugging to work in CF 8 and Eclipse. Eclipse is running on my local machine and CF 8 is running on a non-local "intraweb" development server.

I think I have everything setup correctly:

- RDS Working fine
- Server configured to allow line debugging on port 5005 (port 5005 is not being used on server)
- Added -DDEBUGGER_SERVER_PORT=5005  to the jvm.config file to force the debugging service to use port 5005.
- In the RDS Configuration in Eclipse, the "test connection" is successful.

In RDS configuration, the "Test Debugger" button returns "Test debugger failed" with details that the server is listening on port 5005 but is not the port set in CF Administrator, which doesn't make sense since it IS the port that is set in CF Administrator.

If I restart the CF Server and hit the "test debugger" button, I will get the "test debugger was successful" message, but if I then hit it again a second time and on subsequent times, the connection will fail.  (Trying to run the debug configuration directly after a restart will also fail.)

Would anyone have any ideas?

Thanks   Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.  We had a special firewall setup (outside of windows server) and the port was being blocked.  Unblocked the port, and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem too.  If you are using IIS, turn off compression for Application Files (found in the "Service" tab in properties).

Comment: We are using IIS 6, but the compression for application files option is not turned on in the "service" tab properties.